# I don't understand the meaning and "naran" in this sentence 早く日曜日にならんかな

Tags: words, verbs, conjugations

I don't understand the meaning of ならん in this sentence:

> 早く日曜日に**ならん**かな

Does ならん come from ならぶ? Or come from なる? How it's conjugated? What's that ん in ならん...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word is **nar-an**, a negated form of the verb **なる**. The standard negation of the verb may be known to you as **ならない**. The utterance you ask about can be rephrased as 早く日曜日にならないかな.

Comment: This ならん as a casual version of ならない sounds like it's from somewhere in the Western Japan (probably except Kansai, where ならへん is prevalent).
Tokyoite may say なんねえ(かな) colloquially, when meaning ならない(かな).

Comment: It's not a 'casual form of ならない'; it's a form of the old ならぬ, For that matter, Tokyoites do use it, mostly older male ones.

Comment: @Nothingatall Please address the appropriate people when you comment. Since your comment is not addressed to anyone specific, it is automatically addressed to me as the answerer. But I didn't make the claim that your comment attributes to me. Please correct your mistake.